# FCKEditor: Access content area

Tags: javascript, fckeditor, clicklistener

I'm having problems doing this. I can't access the content area object. I need it to attach a click listener.

```
var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor( editorName ) ;
        oFCKeditor.BasePath = o.editorPath;
        if (o.configPath) {
            oFCKeditor.Config["CustomConfigurationsPath"] =     o.configPath +"?" + ( new Date() * 1 ) ;
        }
        oFCKeditor.Width = '100%';
        oFCKeditor.Height = '100%';
        oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea();
        oFCKeditor.setEnabled(true);

        alert(oFCKeditor.EditorDocument);
        alert(oFCKeditor.EditorWindow);
                    alert(FCK);
```

I also tried accessing there objects from different parts inside FCKEditor's code, but no luck.

What am I doing wrong? What is the usual way to do this?

Thanks

Edit: when I do this:

```
var oEditor = FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance(editorName) ;
alert(oEditor.EditorDocument);
```

after creating the editor it works, but only when I'm stepping through it with a debugger, otherwise it's undefined. So it's probably a timing issue. But where am I supposed to get that then?

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.cksource.com/FCKeditor_2.x/Developers_Guide/JavaScript_API#Events

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">      
        var object;

        function FCKeditor_OnComplete(editorInstance) 
        {            
            object = editorInstance;   
        }
        function Display()
        {
          alert( object.GetHTML());
        }
   </script>
```

Comment: You should add some explanation when posting answers.